# Can std::threads be created / destroyed from global variables in a Windows DLL?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm creating a logging object which performs the real file writing work on a separate `std::thread`, and offers an interface to a log command buffer, syncing the caller threads and the one worker thread.  Access to the buffer is protected by a mutex, there's an atomic bool for the worker thread exit condition, and I'm using Windows native Events as a signal to wake up the worker thread when new commands arrive.  The object's constructor spawns the worker thread so it is immediately available.  The worker thread is simply a while loop checking the exit condition, with in the loop a blocking wait for the signal.  The object's destructor finally just sets the exit condition, signals the thread to wake up and joins it to ensure it's down before the object is fully destroyed.

Seems simple enough, and when using such an object somewhere in a function it works nicely.  However, when declaring such an object as a global variable to have it usable for everyone it stops working.  I'm on Windows, using Visual Studio 2017 with the 2015 tool chain.  My project is a DLL plugin for another application.

The things I tried so far:

- Start the thread in the constructor of the global object.  This however makes the main thread hang immediately when my DLL is loaded.  Pausing the app in the debugger reveals we're in the std lib, at a point where the main thread should have launched the worker thread and is now stuck waiting for a condition variable, presumably one that is signaled by the worker thread once it is launched?
- Delay-construct the thread on demand when we first use the global object from somewhere else.  This way constructing it goes nicely without a hang.  However, when signalling the worker thread to exit from the destructor, the signal is sent, but the join on the worker thread now hangs.  Pausing the app in the debugger reveals our main thread is the only one still alive, and the worker thread is already gone?  A breakpoint placed in the worker thread function right before the close brace reveals it is never hit; the thread must be getting killed?
- I also tried to start the thread via a `std::future`, starting it up async, and that one launches perfectly fine from the constructor in global objects.  However, when the future tries to join the thread in the destructor, it hangs as well; here again no worker thread to be detected anymore while no breakpoint gets hit in it.

What could be going on?  I can't imagine it's because the thread construction and destruction takes place outside main() so to speak; these std primitives should really be available at such moments, right?  Or is this Windows specific and is the code running in the context of `DllMain`'s `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` / `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` events, where starting up threads might wreak havoc due to thread local storage not yet being up and running or such? (would it?)

**EDIT -- added code sample**

The following is an abbreviation/simplification of my code; it probably doesn't even compile but it gets the point across I hope :)

```
class LogWriter {
public:
    LogWriter() :
        m_mayLive(true) {
        m_writerThread = std::thread(&C_LogWriter::HandleLogWrites, this); // or in initializer list above, same result
    };
    ~LogWriter() {
        m_mayLive = false;
        m_doSomething.signal();
        if (m_writerThread.joinable()) {
            m_writerThread.join();
        }
    };
    void AddToLog(const std::string& line) { // multithreaded client facing interface
        {
            Locker locker; // Locker = own RAII locker class
            Lock(locker); // using a mutex here behind the scenes
            m_outstandingLines.push_back(line);
        }
        m_doSomething.signal();
    }

private:
    std::list<std::string> m_outstandingLines; // buffer between worker thread and the rest of the world
    std::atomic<bool> m_mayLive; // worker thread exit signal
    juce::WaitableEvent m_doSomething; // signal to wake up worker thread; no std -- we're using other libs as well
    std::thread m_writerThread;

    int HandleLogWrites() {
        do {
            m_doSomething.wait(); // wait for input; no busy loop please

            C_Locker locker; // access our line buffer; auto-released at end of loop iteration
            Lock(locker);

            while (!m_outstandingLines.empty()) {
                WriteLineToLog(m_outstandingLines.front());
                m_outstandingLines.pop_front();
                if (!m_outstandingLines.empty()) {
                    locker.Unlock(); // don't hog; give caller threads some room to add lines to the buffer in between
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
                    Lock(locker);
                }
            };
        } while (m_mayLive); // atmoic bool; no need to mutex it

        WriteLineToLog("LogWriter shut down"); // doesn't show in the logs; breakpoints here also aren't being hit
        return 0;
    }

    void WriteLineToLog(const std::string& line) {
        ... fopen, fprintf the line, flush, close ...
    }

    void Lock(C_Locker& locker) {
        static LocalLock lock; // LocalLock is similar to std::mutex, though we're using other libs here
        locker.Lock(&lock);
    }
};



class Logger {
public:
    Logger();
    ~Logger();
    void operator() (const char* text, ...) { // behave like printf
        std::string newLine;
        ... vsnprintf -> std::string ...
        m_writer.AddToLog(newLine);
    }

private:
    LogWriter m_writer;
};



extern Logger g_logger; // so everyone can use g_logger("x = %d\n", x);
// no need to make it a Meyer Singleton; we have no other global objects interfering
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheal, use [thread local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: @VictorGubin: Thanks for that -- I didn't know `thread_local` was a thing.  But in my case the global object can't use that storage class; it is going to be created on whatever thread the host app loads my plugin from, and should always be available to future host calls from other host threads even after the host thread that created us itself terminates (can that be a thing?).  I therefore wanted a static object, which is constructed and thus usable as soon as the plugin dll is loaded, and is available up to the dll detach.

Comment: With C++ 11, you can simply use classic Mayers Singleton and forget about the DLLMain generaly. C++ compiler/linker will generate you right code for what you wanting.

Comment: Oh, DLLMain and the singleton here are just red herrings I think.  The problem here seems to be that starting a std::thread from a global object's constructor seems to bring UB, as well as signalling/joining such thread from a global object's destructor.  Using the Meyers Singleton pattern here indeed solves the constructor issue by delaying it until well in DllMain so to speak (same as when I manually delay the creation of the actual worker thread), but the destruct part remains unsolved...

Comment: I'll update my post with the code design I'm using to clear things up

Comment: Style advice: polling really isn't the way to go. A C++ `condition_variable` can efficiently be waited on in the writer thread. It requires a real `std::mutex` though, for efficiency.

Comment: @VictorGubin not in a DLL, the destructors still get run in `DllMain` and thus loader lock.

Comment: @Mgetz rather in some __crt_DLLMain, which calls user's DLL main as well as destructors. Order is depends on compiler/linker you are using.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm not really polling here.  The outer while loop is parked on a Windows Event (the m_doSomething member wraps one of those), and the inner while is there just to flush out any buffered lines there are (to prevent data loss on crash).  There really shouldn't be more than 1 to 4 lines in the buffer when the thread awakes anyway.

Comment: @CarlColijn: If you're not polling, why are you bothering with the 10 ms sleep? Also, you don't want to call `fopen` for every line. If you do have multiple lines, open the file once, and write everything you have. It seems that your "hogging" problem is due to a bad design elsewhere. For instance, there's also a speed gain possible if `HandleLogWrites()` swaps `m_outstandingLines` with a local empty list under mutex lock (two pointer writes), and then writes out that local list at its own pace.

Comment: @MSalters: all good points, but this was more of a summary than the real code :) It's far from matured atm; the part about the hogging is from the state this code came from: previously it was an in-thread Write-To-Disk-Now-Before-This-Thread-Crashes system: hence reopen/flush/close. Swapping lists is not an option since we later on want to be able to augment dumped lines after the fact (the list will remain longer in memory before being written). And I'm thinking about a std::vector ring buffer anyway full of pre-allocated std::strings to get the heap out of the equation.

Comment: @VictorGubin it's irrelevant, the entire call tree back to the kernel thread is in loader lock regardless and thus unsafe.

Comment: @CarlColijn have you considered [`FreeLibraryWhenCallbackReturns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-freelibrarywhencallbackreturns)? Or [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread)? Both allow you to keep your own use count of your DLL and make sure the DLL doesn't get unloaded before you clean up. See the link on MSalter's answer below.

Comment: @Mgetz: Thanks for the info.  Problem here is that we can only have our own dll and helper dlls are not an option; the host and our user's workflow doesn't allow for it. Another gotcha is that I need this code to be as cross platform as possible (I'm developing on Windows now but it also has to run on OSX and later Linux), though a quick #ifdef here and there is acceptable ofc.

Comment: To everyone: I've already made a workaround in that the host is (for current versions) reliably sending an exit message to our plugin somewhere before it unloads us, and I just stop the worker thread there.  This means logging from then on is not possible, but ah well, there's not much going on afterwards anyway...

Answer (score 4):

Since you're writing a DLL in C++, you have to understand how "globals" in DLL's work. The compiler sticks their initialization in `DllMain`, before anything else that you would do there. But there are some strict rules what you can do in `DllMain`, as it runs under loader lock. The short summary is that you can't call anything in another DLL because that DLL cannot be loaded while **your** `DllMain` is running. Calling `CreateThread` is definitely not allowed, not even if wrapped inside a `std::thread::thread` constructor.

The problem with the destructor is quite possibly because your DLL has exited (can't tell without code). The DLL unloads before the EXE, and their respective globals are also cleaned up in that order. Any attempt to log from a destructor in an EXE will fail for obvious reasons.

There is no simple solution here. Andrei Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ Design" has a reasonable solution for logging in the non-DLL case, but you'll need to harden that for use in a DLL. An alternative is to check in your logging functions if your logger still exists. You can use a named mutex for that. If your log function fails in `OpenMutex`, then either the logger does not exist yet or it no longer exists.

Comment: I suspected DllMain being the culprit here, but I hoped (just like in an .exe) that the global environment would already have been set up sufficiently enough before any C++ code would be ran, and I would thus be fine.  So for init I will definitely need to delay until out of DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH so to speak (where Victor's suggestion of Meyers Singletons is a solution), but then destruction indeed remains a hairy thing.  When I signal the thread to quit the thread is already down- killed by the OS?  I'm tempted to just detach the thread and not `.join` it on destruct... feeling dirty already :)

Comment: @Carl : DllMain has another culprit here, `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`. If you'd try to create a new thread from `DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)`, Windows would need to call your own `DllMain` again on the new thread that's being created, but that fails due to loader lock. There really should be only one `DllMain` executing in your program at any one time.

Comment: FWIW @RaymondChen [Has written about this in the past](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180907-00/?p=99675)

Answer (score 0):

Think I've encountered that destruction issue with DLLs to use with Unity.
The only solution I found back then was to essentially give up true global variables that would need cleanup.
Instead I put them in a separate class which is instantiated only a single time into a global pointer by some custom launch function. Then my DLL got a "quit()" function also called by the user of the DLL. The quit function correctly destroys the instance carrying the global variables.

Probably not the smoothest solution and you have a pointer-indirection on every access to the global variables, but it turned out to be comfortable for serializing the state of the global variables as well.